# Why is the DOM Explorer always empty when debugging a Cordova App in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: cordova, debugging, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-mobile

I've been struggling with this one for months (on and off) and getting nowhere. We have a Cordova (actually Ionic 3) app that runs almost perfectly on Windows Phone however can't be debugged with Visual Studio 2017. Up until now we've been able to use other methods of debugging but it's getting extremely tedious.

The DOM Explorer and Javascript Console windows both appear however both remain empty and when execute any Javascript in the console it displays "You are not currently attached to a supported page or app."

This doesn't appear to be app specific - the same thing happens even if we create a blank Cordova app in Visual Studio and try to debug that.

Also doesn't make any difference whether we're debugging a real device or the emulator.

[image: How the DOM Explorer and Javascript console appear while app is running]

[image: Current Visual Studio Version]

Will literally accept just about any suggestions at this point - feels like we've tried everything.

Comment: update to 15.8.5 and try it again

Comment: Updated (took forever) but hasn't made any difference unfortunately. Have tried it with both "Mobile Emulator 10.0.14393.0 WXGA 4.5 inch 1GB" and "Mobile Emulator 10.0.15254.0 WXGA 4.5 inch 1GB" with the same result each time. Debugger appears to connect at some level but neither DOM Explorer or Javascript console work.

Comment: [report the issue to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got to the bottom of this but I did discover that the DOM debugger works as expected with Visual Studio 2015 so I've been using that instead. Bit of a nuisance but better then nothing!